Karpenter consolidation happening on non-scheduled time
Recently I have upgraded Karpenter version to v0.34.0 and along with that disruption feature comes where we can schedule the node consolidation to specific hours. I have added the disruption policy but even after that karpenter is consolidating nodes on unscheduled hours.
Below is the code, I am using. Is there anything needs to be fixed in code
*apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1beta1   
 kind: NodePool
 metadata:
    name: application   spec:
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          provisioner: karpenter
          nodegroup: application
          usage: application   
      spec:
        nodeClassRef:
          apiVersion: karpenter.k8s.aws/v1beta1
          kind: EC2NodeClass
          name: default
        requirements:
          - key: "karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-category"
            operator: In
            values: ["c", "m", "r"]
        taints:
          - key: usage
            value: application
            effect: NoSchedule
    %{  if var.consolidation_enabled  }
    disruption:
      consolidationPolicy: WhenUnderutilized
      budgets:
      - nodes: "0"
      - nodes: "1"
        schedule: "05 7 * * *" # Schedule for 5:40 AM EST
        duration: 30m
    %{  endif }
    limits:
        cpu: 600*


Did you find an answer to this? It's my understanding that the schedule sets when you DON'T want consolidation.  I would love it if I could set when I DO want consolidation to happen.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
